Visa granted to baby with wrong date (wrong year)
We (myself, my wife, and our toddler) applied for a short-term Portugal Schengen visa (from VFS Bangalore to the New Delhi consulate) from July 7 2024 to July 14 2024. My wife and I were granted a visa with the correct dates. Our baby was granted a visa with the correct month and date but from 2027 to 2028! How can we correct this? (The other complication is that we will be travelling for a couple of weeks to Singapore from April 30 2024. So either we need to get it corrected quickly or after almost a month.)

You need to reach out to the consulate ASAP and tell them the issued visa is erroneous.

I wrote an email. Unfortunately these chaps don’t respond to emails and don’t pick up the phone.

Did you contact VFS?

Not yet. Will contact them too.

Unfortunately, VFS asked me to contact the embassy. Now I am in a fix.
